# How to improve the `M-! command` output

Tags: shell-command, newlines

I found this really cool in emacs

```
M-! t
```

t is ~/bin/t, and runs tests for whatever thing I'm working on.
I added `~/bin/` to my `/etc/path.d/`, and
I always use `emacs -nw`.

My issue is, the command output is not displayed properly in Emacs.

[image]

Newlines are messed up, and there's a `^M` shown in the screen.

How can I tell `M-! command` to give me a more realistic view of the
output, **as if it was typed in a true bash terminal**

Comment: I removed the `emacs25` tag.  Please do not use irrelevant tags in your posts.

Comment: What @Dan said. I've removed the same tag several times now. And `elisp`, which is about the language itself, not about how to do XYZ in Elisp.

Comment: I think you have to use a custom shell process to get all escape sequences and apply colors correctly. But I think ansi-colors.el is broken. However I do know that the package xterm-color is working.

Comment: thanks for mentioning  xterm-color, so how do I use it?

Comment: The shell command functionality provides only a dumb terminal, so "as if it was typed in a true bash terminal" is very different.  You might want to update your test script to support dumb terminals; or you could try using the `term.el` process filter `term-emulate-terminal`.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
(defun my-shell-process ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((buf "my-shell-process")
        (coding-system-for-read 'binary)
        (process-environment (nconc
                              (list (format "TERM=%s" "notdumb"))
                              process-environment)))
    (start-process "my-shell-process"
                   buf
                   "/bin/bash")
    (let ((proc (get-buffer-process buf)))
      (set-process-filter proc 'my-filter)
      (accept-process-output proc 0.1))))

(defun my-filter (proc output)
  (let ((buf (process-buffer proc)))
    (with-current-buffer buf
      (goto-char (point-max))
      (setq truncate-lines t)
      (insert (xterm-color-filter output)))))
```

You need to send a command to the process this way `(process-send-string "my-shell-process" "ls -la\n")`

Comment: is my use case so niche that emacs doesn't have a package or builtin for this?

Comment: Maybe there is a package for this, but I doubt it.